# Alternative isomorphism from $(R/I)\otimes_R (R/J)$ to $R/(I+J)$ (R-module homomorphism)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

I see from many sources (e.g. http://math.stanford.edu/~simonr/math121hw2.pdf) that the isomorphism map is defined as $\psi((x+I)\otimes (y+J))=xy+(I+J)$ (multiplication).

Is it possible to define the map as $\psi((x+I)\otimes (y+J))=x+y+(I+J)$ (Addition) instead?

I tried but am stuck at a dubious step: namely is $r[(x+I)\otimes(y+J)]=(rx+I)\otimes (ry+J)$ (multiply $r$ to both terms) or $(rx+I)\otimes (y+J)$ (multiply $r$ to just one term).

If it is the latter, I believe the "additive" isomorphism approach doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is the latter, and I believe this doesn't work. Why don't you try checking if the additive and multiplicative structures on $R/(I+J)$ are isomorphic?

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote, though... this is actually a nice question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there was an $R$-module isomorphism
\begin{align}
\psi_a\colon \qquad R/I \otimes_R R/J &\to \left(R/(I+J), +\right)\\
(x + I) \otimes (y + J) &\mapsto x + y + (I + J).
\end{align}
In particular we would have
$$
\psi_a((x + I) \otimes (0 + J)) = x + (I + J)
$$
for every $x \in R$. But tensoring by $0$ always gives the $0$ element in a tensor product, and since $\psi_a$ is a function it must follow that $R/I$ has exactly one element, i.e. $I = R$.

---

More in general, suppose that there are two $R$-module isomorphisms
\begin{align}
\psi_a\colon R/I \otimes_R R/J &\to \left(R/(I+J), +\right)\\
\psi_m\colon R/I \otimes_R R/J &\to \left(R/(I+J), *\right).
\end{align}
Then $\psi_a \circ \psi_m^{-1}$ induces an isomorphism of $R/(I+J)$-modules between $\left(R/(I+J), +\right)$ and $\left(R/(I+J), *\right)$, so it is enough to prove that $(A,+)$ and $(A,*)$ cannot be isomorphic as $A$-modules for any ring $A \neq \{0\}$.

Indeed, suppose otherwise and call $\varphi$ the isomorphism. Then for every $a\in A$ we have
$$
\varphi(0) = \varphi(a0) = a \varphi(0)
$$
and choosing $a = 0$ gives $\varphi(0) = 0$. On the other hand for every $a \in A$ we have
$$
\varphi(a) = \varphi(a + 0) = \varphi(a)\varphi(0) = 0.
$$
Hence $\varphi$ cannot be an isomorphism unless $A = \{0\}$.